# How to access a Spring bean from one service in another in Unit Test?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a web application with this project structure:

```
app-name
   |- web
   |- service-A
   +- service-B
```

Each java project has its own application context XML configuration/annotation. Now I am writing tests in service-B, that uses some Spring beans from service-A. 
At this point, I have a BaseTest defined in Service-B with the following configuration.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-KA-service-test.xml", "classpath:service_a_test.mockspring.xml" })
public class BaseTest {
 ...
}
```

and Junit Test in Service-B extends BaseTest as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-WS-service-test.xml", "classpath:service_b_test.mockspring.xml" })
public class GeoInformationServiceImpl_2_Test extends BaseTest {
...
}
```

If I remove "extends BaseTest" from service B, it throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext" because some of the beans from Service-A are not found. Obvious!
But If I keep this association, I come across numerous other issues like tests failing etc.
Another issue in my configuration is, 
Service-A refers a bean B1 in Service-B. Bean B1 reads a file in "src/test/resources/mockdata/geo_results.csv". But this statement fails when B1 is referred inside Service A tests, but works fine inside Service B tests.

My question, what is the legitimate way to refer a Spring bean in service-B from service-A inside a JUnit Test?

Comment: Putting the unit testing aside, how are the projects are supposed to communicate with each other?Are they separated in different environments? If you are doing integration testing you can deploy other project before the test runs so it's not clear why you are referencing beans directly. If it's interprocess communication then you should do integration testing of the full chain.

Comment: ServiceA, ServiceB are eclipse java projects and are packaged in the same ear file. For maintenance purpose, it has been segregated into multiple java projects. Common services are mostly in ServiceA project and used by other services.